# DisplayTag - export filename global property does not work

Tags: displaytag

I am using `DisplayTag 1.2` and I have a problem when I try to add a global property for the filename of an export. 
When I define a property using `setProperty` inside the tableTag everything works fine:

```
<display:table>
    ...
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="export.xls" />
</display:table>
```

But when I add this property in my global `diaplaytag.properties` file:

```
...
export.excel=true
export.excel.filename=export.xls
...
```

This doen't work, it now uses the requestURI parameter as name (as is default I guess).
All my other properties in the `displaytag.properties` file work fine but not the ones for the filename.

Please I could use some help with this as there are ***a lot*** of pages in my application which otherwise need to be manually adjusted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Displaytag was using an old version of the properties file!